# Is there any way to get all the changes of the google drive from its beginning in java

Tags: java, google-drive-api, drive

Is there any way for getting all the changes of Google Drive from the beginning of the drive and if there is no way please mention it if you have any official documentation also I'm fine.

Hi people,

I have a case where I need to get all the changes from the Drive from the beginning in Java,

I tried multiple approaches like

```java
String pagetoken = "";
        ChangeList changes = drive.changes().list(pagetoken).execute();
```

getting error like

```
400 Bad Request
{
  "code" : 400,
  "errors" : [ {
    "domain" : "global",
    "location" : "pageToken",
    "locationType" : "parameter",
    "message" : "Invalid Value",
    "reason" : "invalid"
  } ],
  "message" : "Invalid Value"
}
```

Approach 2

```java
String pagetoken = null;
        ChangeList changes = drive.changes().list(pagetoken).execute();
```

getting error like

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Required parameter pageToken must be specified.
```

Approach 3

```java
String pagetoken = "1";
        ChangeList changes = drive.changes().list().execute();
```

getting error like

```
Expected 1 arguments but found 0 for list parameter
```

here drive is the google drive object and I'm using the Google Drive library in Java

complete code

```java
import com.google.api.services.drive.Drive;
import com.google.api.services.drive.model.Change;
import com.google.api.services.drive.model.ChangeList;
import com.google.api.client.googleapis.javanet.GoogleNetHttpTransport;
import com.google.api.client.json.jackson2.JacksonFactory;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.security.GeneralSecurityException;
import java.util.List;

public class GoogleDriveChangesExample {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            Drive driveService = new Drive.Builder(
                    GoogleNetHttpTransport.newTrustedTransport(),
                    JacksonFactory.getDefaultInstance(),
                    yourCredentials)
                    .setApplicationName("Your Application Name")
                    .build();

            ChangeList changes;
            String pageToken = null;
            changes = drive.changes().list(pageToken).execute();
           

        } catch (GeneralSecurityException | IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

So is there any way for getting all the changes of the drive from the beginning of the drive?